# How to get a content of file which is being written by an application?

Tags: delphi, winapi, file-io, process, hook

This application always create a file when you activate a function (lets say, a log file). This file cannot be opened during the running - but I need its content before application closes (another process uses it, so I cant even view it). Is there a way to "hook" it somehow?

Im working with Delphi, but I accept any other solution.
So, summary, I need to know what file application created (it always creates other, but in the same directory) and the content it wrote. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should change the application that writes the file. It needs to share the file for reading, rather than use exclusive share mode.

Comment: Its an already-done exe file, I cant change anything on it

Comment: Then you're out of luck, unless you want to get *really* dirty and perform low-level reading of the hard drive (would only work on local drives, require that you know the disk format of the disk, *and* that you know how to navigate a disk using only low-level sector reads).

Comment: *OR* (also dirty) hook into the operating system or the application and modify the application's CreateFile call to open the file in a read-compatible mode.

Comment: It would be so much better if you sorted out the other program. Talk to its developer.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround:

copy the file, and operate on the cloned one:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/backupcopy-files-that-are-in-use-or-locked-in-windows/

Comment: If there is an API for it, Delphi can do it as well